# A question in functional analysis about selfadjoint operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, self-adjoint-operators

In Hilbert space $u$, Let $T_1$,$T_2$ is selfadjoint operator, if exit $c>0$ such that $cI\le T_1\le T_2$, prove $T_1$,$T_2$ have a bounded inverse operator and $c^{-1}I\ge T_1^{-1}\ge T_2^{-1}$.

I have proved $T_1$ and $T_2$ have inverse operators by using the relation between the range of the adjoint operator and the null space of the operator. How do I prove the second half of the problem and the boundedness of the inverse operator?

Comment: @geetha290krm in this question $I$ is identity operator ,I forget to write

Comment: @ChadK I know $T_1,T_2$ is invertible.I do not understand why $c^{-1}I\ge T_1^{-1}\ge T_2^{-1}$. to be exact $T_1^{-1}\ge T_2^{-1}$.